Scheduling Queries in redshift using cloudformation
I have few queries in aws redshift which I want to schedule using redshift schedule feature so that I can run those queries according to specific requirements. I want to do this work using cloudformation yaml script. I have been trying to do this but I am unable to find out which properties/keys will be used in the script. I have checked the documentation as well but couldn't get any working solution.
To make schedule work I require 2 resources which are iam role with relevant permissions and redshift schedule resource. Below is the snippet of the query schedule resource which I am using
  ScheduledQuery1:
    Type: AWS::Redshift::ScheduledAction
    Properties:
      Enable: true
      IamRole: !GetAtt RedshiftSchedulerRole.Arn
      ScheduledActionName: ScheduledQuery1
      ScheduledActionDescription: "Runs query 1 every day at 12:00 AM PST"
      Schedule: cron(45 14 * * ? *)  # Every day at 12:00 AM PST (adjust as needed)
     TargetAction:
        #Query: "SELECT * FROM foodics_reports.foodics_daily_sales limit 100"
        #ExecuteStatement:
          #Database: dfsftdb
          #SQL: "SELECT * FROM foodics_reports.foodics_daily_sales limit 100"

TargetAction section of script is problematic where i tried multiple ways to make it work but it always gave this error Properties validation failed for resource ScheduledQuery1 with message: [#/TargetAction: extraneous key [Database] is not permitted, #/TargetAction: extraneous key [Sql] is not permitted, #/TargetAction: extraneous key [Database] is not permitted, #/TargetAction: extraneous key [Sql] is not permitted, #/TargetAction: extraneous key [Database] is not permitted, #/TargetAction: extraneous key [Sql] is not permitted
Kindly provide solution of this error, what is wrong and what is the solution/ correct working yaml script for this scenario.
Tried multiple keys in target action section and gone through the documentation to solve this problem but didnot find the solution.

I’m 99% sure setting up a “query editor” scheduled query isn’t supported using any kind of automation. Best u can do is schedule a lambda that calls the query (and if it’s long running doesn’t wait for it to return). Set up a scheduled query through the editor and then look at the event bridge rule it creates, it’s actually pointing to some internal redshift thingy query editor created I think. I mean maybe u can backward engineer it, love to know if u get it to work. I gave up on it and just used cloud formation to set up the proper iam stuff so I could then go and add the scheduled query myself.
